# How to fit all pixel sized images in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a web application where I want to display product like in e-commerce website. The images of random dimension have to be fit in a particular box.
I have tried following code but it distorts the image if height is more than width, but looks perfectly if it is vice versa.

```
<div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="padding:2px;">
                    <a href="#" style=" text-decoration: none;"><img  src="images/abc.jpg" style="width:100%;height:220px;" /></a></a>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body w3-card" style="padding-top:0px;background-color:#ebebeb;">
                    <a href="#" class="pull-left" style=" text-decoration: none;"><h5 style="margin-bottom:0px;" ><b>Product One</b></h5>
                    <p class="pull-left" style="margin-top:0px;color:#6e6e6e;margin-bottom:0px;"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 10,000/-</p></a>                       
                </div>


            </div>
```

Comment: by setting img dimensions, you are losing aspect ratio on img. can you do width and height auto for img

Comment: Can you use `background-image` instead?

Comment: Set `max-width: 100%; height: auto;` on the image. Add `overflow:hidden;` on the image container if necessary.

Comment: There's also the [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property, but it's not universally supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the answer with little modification from the comment.

```
<div class="panel panel-default text-center">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding:2px;overflow:hidden;">
        <a href="#" style=" text-decoration: none;"><img  src="images/abc.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; height: 100%;" /></a></a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body w3-card" style="padding-top:0px;background-color:#ebebeb;">
        <a href="#" class="pull-left" style=" text-decoration: none;"><h5 style="margin-bottom:0px;" ><b>Product One</b></h5>
            <p class="pull-left" style="margin-top:0px;color:#6e6e6e;margin-bottom:0px;"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 10,000/-</p></a>                       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add another attributes in your style :

```
    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding:2px;">
                <a href="#" style=" text-decoration: none;"><img  src="images/abc.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto;max-width:100px;" /></a></a>
    </div>
```

Does it work now?

Comment: I want the image to proportionately fit in div without distorting image like in e-commerce website.

Comment: then set one of your attributes either width or height auto :
    height: auto; or
    width : auto ;
Because Setting both width and height parameters will stretch and distort your images to fit those dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care much about Edge / IE, you can use `object-fit` like in the example below:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default text-center">
  <div class="panel-heading" style="padding:2px;height:200px;">
    <a href="#" style=" text-decoration: none;"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" style="width:100%;height:100%;object-fit:cover;" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body w3-card" style="padding-top:0px;background-color:#ebebeb;">
    <a href="#" class="pull-left" style=" text-decoration: none;">
      <h5 style="margin-bottom:0px;"><b>Product One</b></h5>
      <p class="pull-left" style="margin-top:0px;color:#6e6e6e;margin-bottom:0px;"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 10,000/-</p>
    </a>
  </div>
```

If you **do** care and **if** you can use `background-image`, i'd advise you going the way below:

```css
div.panel-heading {
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1000x1000');
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default text-center">
  <div class="panel-heading" style="padding:2px;height:200px;">
    <a href="#" style=" text-decoration: none;"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body w3-card" style="padding-top:0px;background-color:#ebebeb;">
    <a href="#" class="pull-left" style=" text-decoration: none;">
      <h5 style="margin-bottom:0px;"><b>Product One</b></h5>
      <p class="pull-left" style="margin-top:0px;color:#6e6e6e;margin-bottom:0px;"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 10,000/-</p>
    </a>
  </div>
```